# Can you subscribe and publish to the same ActiveMQ topic

Tags: activemq-classic, publish-subscribe, jms-topic

I have a software component that puts a message on a topic - its for 'keep-alive' functionality, testing to see if the components are still running.  The component that puts the message on the topic also needs to listen on the same topic.  ActiveMQ isn't responding - i.e. the subscribe isn't working for the item that published.

Is there a setting anywhere in ActiveMQ where this functionality can be changed?

We're currently developing on a single node, but will be deploying to multiple nodes, where it will be important for this message to be picked up by the same software component on other nodes, but we haven't tried that yet and don't know if it will work, or how reliable that is.  We would be okay if the behaviour was known (i.e. a setting somewhere in the ActiveMQ configuration exists), but we don't.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ has no limitation that would cause this. Check the 'noLocal' setting on your JMS subscriber. If set to 'true' it will ignore messages that are produced from the same connection.

Sounds like you want noLocal=false